# What are the differences between PNL and PNR messages?

Tags: airline-operations, passenger

What are the differences between Passenger Name List (PNL) and Passenger Name Record (PNR) message in CRS systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PNR is a passenger's/party's record.

PNL is the full list of all the PNR's.

**Example:**

```
7 01SMITH/JOHN...
```

John Smith is a party of 1, that's the PNR entry. And he is number 7 on the PNL.

Comment: And is this PNL message sent to the destination authorities? if so, what is PNRGOV message?